# Check if a ip_port has ssl enabled in its application layer

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl

I have an application A(in c++) which communicates to ip_port B via openssl.

The problem is when I initiate a BIO_do_connect() function to a non-ssl host, it simply blocks without coming out. The BIO_set_nbio() is not helping either.

My question is, are there any way to check if the ip_port socket has ssl enabled ? some function which just returns true/false.

Thanks,

Comment: Sockets or ports do not have a notion of being SSL enabled. SSL is running on the application layer, not the transport layer. Finding out whether or not SSL is running on a particular port only works by trying a handshake, which either fails or succeeds.

Comment: Yes, SSL is in application layer. But I should have been little more specific in the question.

The BIO_do_connect() function from openssl blocks indefinitely if the target socket doesn't have ssl library in its application layer.  Are there any way to examine the same with openssl ?

Comment: Just set a read timeout on the socket before you connect it. If you get a timeout straight away, it's not responding to the SSL handshake.